# CMTime parameter is received with unexpected value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cmtime

I'm trying to pass a CMTime value as a function parameter... My function looks like:

```
getThumbnailForVideo:(AVAsset *)video
              atTime:(CMTime)time;
```

so somewhere I'm calling

```
[instance getThumbnailForVideo:video
                        atTime:thumbnailTime];
```

If there I print `thumbnailTime` I see the expected value that in my case is simply `kCMTimeZero`(`thumbnailTime.timeScale` is 1, `thumbnailTime.value` is 0)

But if I print `time` from within the function, I get a really weird value:
`time.value` is 6089232256, `time.timescale` is 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you showed a bit more relevant code.